# Euclidean Distance of 2 points in opencv warped image

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, euclidean-distance, perspectivecamera

I have an image having a scale of cm/mm. I have warped it using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform` and then I measure the Euclidean distance between 2 points of the scale. I know that warped images give measurement in mm or cm but not a pixel. Now when I measure the distance between 2 points that is not the same as on the scale in mm.

The sample Image is attached. Any help will be appreciated

[image]

Comment: In order to warp an image you should use `warpPerspective` rather than `getPerspectiveTransform` (which only calculates the transform instead of applying it.

Also, please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes once I have transformed the image then do `warpPerspective`, but still, the measurements are not accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it fixed. The problem was that the warped image formed was incorrect. It happens because of the ordering sequence of the corner coordinates. After trying the 16 combinations I found the correct one and that made it work.